# How to prevent WCF from calling service method multiple times if exception was thrown?

Tags: wcf

Here's a situation. We have a WCF service call with receive timeout being equal to 30 seconds. After 30 seconds the connection is aborted but the call is repeated. As a result, server performs the desired action twice, which is not what we want.

Binding configuration:

```
<netTcpBinding>
            <binding name="DefaultTcpBinding"
                        maxReceivedMessageSize="901048576"
                        closeTimeout="00:00:30"
                        openTimeout="00:00:30"
                        receiveTimeout="00:00:30"
                        sendTimeout="00:00:30"
                        portSharingEnabled="false"
                        hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                        transactionFlow="true"
                        transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                        transferMode="Buffered"
                        maxConnections="50"
                        listenBacklog="50">

                <reliableSession enabled="false"/>
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
                </security>
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="5242880"maxArrayLength="2147483646" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="5242880"/>
            </binding>
        </netTcpBinding>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That should not be the way WCF works, even with a reliable session after a timeout exception another call will not be tried. Are you sure the call is from the same client? Did you try to debug and see if the the proxy catch the exception and where the code go ahead? Try to post some code of the way you call the service

Comment: Thanks, that really was the issue. We had a spring interceptor that retried a call once if it failed.. Thanks a lot, I thought it was some kind of strange WCF feature.